# validate a template text box with database value

Tags: asp.net, validation, gridview, templatefield

I'm developing a website and have a textbox in gridview template field. This textbox collects the input for the "order quantity" which has to be compared against the "available quantity"(stored in the database).

I use RowEditing, RowUpdating and RowCanceling events for edit operations in gridview.

I tried implementing the above requirement with "TextChanged" Event of text box. But the issue is, when the user edits the quantity and clicks on "Update" button, text box event fires first and update button event doesn't fire. So, user is forced to click the "Update" button again.

Is there any work around for the above scenario or any other event used to implement above requirement?

Thanks,
Balaji g

Comment: I didn't clearly understand, What do you need? I mean, Which event should be fired first?

Comment: of course, validation event should be fired first. but on this scenario where, the user will edit only quantily column alone, he will click on "Update" button after editing. once the control goes out of textbox, the text changed event will fire. After the text changed event is fired and validation doen, update button event is not fired. Suppose if the user edits another field after editing quantity, this does not happen. Hope the issue is clear now.

Comment: set a flag variable to false. In text changed event flag=true. Check the value in button's click. If flag==true, do nothing(which means text changed is fired already)

Comment: if u can tell how u calculate quantity than might i help u

Comment: @ling.s, the issue after text changed event, button click event doesn't fire. user is forced to click the "update" button again.

Comment: @amit- computations is, total quantity available - total ordered quantity(by other customers)

Comment: from where u get these two value from database or what ..i m sure u have total in database where is total ordered quantity...how u calculate it

Comment: I calculate it from orders table. ie. from the quantity ordered by the other customers

Comment: can u write a function which take itemid and total quantity  as input and calculate its quantity....

Comment: u mean to say, i can call this function on Range validator's Maximum value attribute?

Comment: yeah you r write write functiion can call it for its maximmum value....i dont think so its problem

Comment: @ amit, can u initiate chat to discuss further to avoid extended discussion. sorry i couldnt initiate it as I don't have enough reputation. ok i will try using functions and post the outcome soon.Thanks.

Comment: you dont have enough reputation to chat...

Comment: wraait i update my anser it might help u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Use RangeValidator For That...

```
    <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" ControlToValidate="YourTexBoxId" 
runat="server" MinimumValue="0" Type="Integer"
MaximumValue='<%# GetQuantity(Eval(TotalQaunt).ToString(),Eval(ItemId).ToString()) %>'
 ErrorMessage="RangeValidator"></asp:RangeValidator>
```

write a function lyk this ON CODE BEHIND

```
string GetQuantity(string totalquantity,string itemid)
{
DO OPERATRION TO GET QUANTITY.....
return quantity;
}
```

Comment: Value is not stored directly in the database. I need to compute this value, for business logic reasons. So, i cant use the above statement.

Comment: how  u will compute value of ur quantity

Comment: i mean the logic u use for it

Comment: I tried using it but its not working as expected. for eg, the funtions returns the quantity 2 but if i enter the value 3 in textbox, it gets executed

Comment: retuir int from ur finction intead of string make int GetQuantity(string totalquantity,string itemid)

Comment: i did the same, i returned int

Comment: it works for me...if u can show ur range validator and function code than might i help u...

Comment: protected int GetAvailableCredit()
    {
        nAvailableCreditLimit = nAvailableCreditLimit - nAllottedCredit;
        return nAvailableCreditLimit;
    }<asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" ControlToValidate="txtInitialCredit" runat="server" MinimumValue="0" Type="Integer" MaximumValue='<%# GetAvailableCredit() %>' ErrorMessage="RangeValidator"></asp:RangeValidator>

Comment: your function return right value did u debug it.....its seems ok here....try to debug and check that ur function return right values or not....and put value less than 0 and check it gives error or not

Comment: Yes, i debugged and found that it returns value, but when i click on "Update" button after entering a out-of-range value, validation msg is not shown and data get updated.

Comment: Now its validating as expected..sorry it was my mistake..I dint specify validation group..But the original issue remains, ie. user is forced to click Update button twice..even the validation message shows up only on second click(btw, i generate update button with the following code:
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkUpdate" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update"
                            Text="Update" OnClientClick="return confirm('Update?')" ValidationGroup="Update"></asp:LinkButton>

Comment: remove onclient click event of ur update button i m sure it will work

Comment: I tried removing onclient click event, however, the issue persists. ie. i have to click the "Update" button twice to fire the update event. Another issue is, when I enter out-of-bound value, validation msg comes up for a moment and then goes off without any further notification on the screen. User has to click twice to see the validation message, even.

Comment: i think there is problem in ur page .....might u refreshed the page for everyfew seconds....otherwise there is no reason that valdation error disappear

Comment: I dont refresh this page for every few seconds..and, the validation error is displaying as expected in other pages..

Comment: problem is in ur page no where else////

Comment: check it..u wil find it for sure./..,.

Comment: You were right, Amit. I set "AutoPostBack" property to true, which was the cause. I removed it and it works fine now. Thanks.

Comment: welcome....dont get panic..remain calm when code doesnt work/...best of luck,,,,....

Comment: I got a similar kind of requirement, wherein, if the status field value is "Pending", i have to disable that row. Is there any way I can use validation to implement it?

Comment: what you mean by disabling row

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd try the CustomValidator.  With the CustomValidator, you can define the validation code in the "_ServerValidate" event handler.

In your validation code, you can call the database to get the current value and then compare it to the submitted value (which would be available via the event handler's ServerValidateEventArgs paramenter if you specify a ControlToValidate).

In order to look up the current value in the database, you'll need to know which record was clicked.  For that, you could either use the row button's CommandArgument property or include a hidden field in your row to store some type of ID.  Then you could capture that ID and use it to look up the desired record in the database.

**Updated with Code**

```
Protected Sub cusCustom_ServerValidate(source As Object, args As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ServerValidateEventArgs)
    Dim cv As CustomValidator = CType(source, CustomValidator)
    Dim HiddenField_ID As HiddenField = CType(cv.Parent.FindControl("HiddenField_ID"), HiddenField)
    *** Use ID to look up value in database ***
End Sub
```

Comment: i couldnt get the current row that is clicked. so i tried some flag but i see that event is not firing up. am i missing something?<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" id="cusCustom" controltovalidate="txtQuantity" onservervalidate="cusCustom_ServerValidate" errormessage="The text must be exactly 8 characters long!" /> Do i need to add any tags for Autopostback to make the event fire?

Comment: When I mentioned the CommandArgument, I was thinking about the OnCommand event. It looks like the CommandArgument isn't available in the CustomValidator's "_ServerValidate" event. So instead, you'll have to do the hidden field option I suggested. You can place a HiddenField in your row. Then in the "_ServerValidate" event, use your CustomValidator control to get to a reference to the HiddenField control. Once you have that, you can pull its value.  When I tested this, it worked.  Also, my button has CausesValidation="True", though that seems to be the default.